# How to install libav-tools into linux machine

Tags: dependencies, installation, redhat, rpm, libav

I need to download and install libav-tools into Redhat(6.3) server that does not have direct connection to internet.(my remote server provider does not provide internet connection)

I tried download the source and ./configure -> make -> make install..

It is showing bulk of dependencies.

Is there any alternative solution or complete package(with all dependencies) to download and install.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any reputable source providing a recent RPM-based libav distribution.  So, the simplest way is to build from source.  In my test environment, only the `yasm` package was required beyond a standard CentOS installation (obtainable from [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) or else compiled from source) for compilation, and the CMMI (configure, make, make install) process completed successfully with a standard libav distribution tarball.  This wastested with libav 9.11, the latest stable version at the time of writing.